# LINQ contains between 2 lists

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a string List and a supplier `List<supplier>`.

string list contains some searched items and supplier list contains a list of supplier object.
Now I need to find all the supplier names that matches with any of the items in the string `List<string>`.

this is one of my failed attempts..

```
var query = some join with the supplier table.
query = query.where(k=>stringlist.contains(k.companyname)).select (...).tolist();
```

any idea how to do that??

### EDIT:

May be my question is not clear enough...I need to find a list of suppliers(not only names,the whole object) where suppliers names matches with the any items in the string list.

If I do

```
query = query.where(k=>k.companyname.contains("any_string")).select (...).tolist();
```

it works. but this is not my requirement.
My requirement is a list of string not a single string.

Comment: Find where they [Intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.intersect.aspx)

Comment: Whats wrong with your pseudocode, you only need to project Name filed in select and it should work.

Comment: What does this have to do with linqtosql?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Following query will return distinct suppliers names which exist in list of names:

```
suppliers.Where(s => stringlist.Contains(s.CompanyName))
         .Select(s => s.CompanyName) // remove if you need whole supplier object
         .Distinct();
```

Generated SQL query will look like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [t0].[FCompanyName]
FROM [dbo].[Supplier] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[CompanyName] IN (@p0, @p1, @p2)
```

BTW consider to use better names, e.g. `companyNames` instead of `stringlist`

Comment: isn't my code is similar to your code. I just dont have that distinct !! But in my code the first query returns 1000 items and after the where it returns nothing. BUT, instead of a list of string if I take a single string. it works

Comment: @kandroid if you need whole supplier object even `suppliers.Where(s => stringlist.Contains(s.CompanyName))` should do the job. Make sure you really have matching suppliers. Maybe company name is not trimmed? Also in your first query you check for company name to match value exactly. In your working sample you check value to be in company name. So, if you have value `org` and company name `Zorg` then it will not match. But your last query will match, thus `org` is contained in `Zorg`

Comment: actually the main problem is query = query.where(k=>stringlist.contains(k.companyname)).select (...).tolist();
here it looks for an exact match...do you know how to make it possible so that it works as 'like' ?

Comment: @kandroid as far as I know Linq to SQL, for local sequence (stringlist) only `Contains` can be translated into SQL. So, in order to use *like* you should move filtering into memory (e.g. with `ToList`): `suppliers.ToList().Where(s => stringlist.Any(x => s.CompanyName.Contains(x)))`. This query will search for all companies which have names like some value in stringlist. But keep in mind, that moving filtering into memory will load all companies into memory

Comment: BTW entity framework can translate `Any` on local collection into sql query.

Answer (score 5):

You could use [Intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136.aspx) for this (for just matching names):

```
var suppliersInBothLists = supplierNames
               .Intersect(supplierObjects.Select(s => s.CompanyName));
```

After your **EDIT**, for suppliers (not just names):

```
var suppliers = supplierObjects.Where(s => supplierNames.Contains(s.CompanyName));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var matches = yourList.Where(x => stringList.Contains(x.CompanyName)).Select(x => x.CompanyName).ToList();
```

Comment: It actually *does* work if you can clarify what you're wanting and/or give us exact names of the objects.  I'll edit to show how to select just the name.

Comment: @kandroid based on your edit, my original answer is exactly what you were looking for.  Check the version prior to edit.

Answer (score 0):

Either use a join as Tim suggested or you could just use a `HashSet` directly. This is much more efficient that using `.Contains` on a `List` as in some of the other answers.

```
var stringSet = new HashSet(stringList);
var result = query.Where(q => stringSet.Contains(q.Name));
```